# Is there any error in the way I am trying to create temporrary object

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, move-constructor, copy-elision

Following is my code: I dont understand why the move constructor does not get invoked.

Mystring.h:

```
#ifndef _MYSTRING_H
#define _MYSTRING_H

#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

#endif

class Mystring{
private:
    char * str;
public:
    Mystring();                         //No arg constructor
    Mystring(char *str);                //Overloaded constructor
    Mystring(const Mystring &source);   //Copy constructor
    Mystring(Mystring &&source);        //Move constructor

    //operator overloading
    bool operator==(const Mystring &rhs);
    bool operator!=(const Mystring &rhs);
    bool operator<(const Mystring &rhs);
    bool operator>(const Mystring &rhs);
    Mystring &operator+(const Mystring &rhs);
    };
```

Mystring.cpp:

```
#include"mystring.h"


Mystring::Mystring():str{nullptr}{
        std::cout<<"No args constructor"<<std::endl;
        }

Mystring::Mystring(char *str){
    this->str = nullptr;
    this->str = new char[strlen(str)+1];
    strcpy(this->str,str);
    std::cout<<"Overloaded constructor called"<<std::endl;
    }

Mystring::Mystring(const Mystring &source){
            delete[] this->str;
            this->str = nullptr;
            this->str = new char[strlen(source.str) + 1];
            strcpy(this->str,source.str);
            std::cout<<"copy constructor called"<<std::endl;
        }

Mystring::Mystring(Mystring &&source){
        this->str  = source.str;
        source.str = nullptr;
        std::cout<<"Move constructor called"<<std::endl;
        }

bool Mystring::operator==(const Mystring &rhs){
    std::cout<<"operator == called"<<std::endl;
    return strcmp(this->str,rhs.str);

    }

bool Mystring::operator!=(const Mystring &rhs){
    std::cout<<"operator != called"<<std::endl;
    return !(operator==(rhs));

    }

bool Mystring::operator <(const Mystring &rhs){
        std::cout<<"operator < called"<<std::endl;
         if(strcmp(this->str,rhs.str) < 0){
             return 0;
             }
         else 
             return 1;
    }

bool Mystring::operator >(const Mystring &rhs){
        std::cout<<"operator > called"<<std::endl;
        return(!(operator<(rhs)));
    }

Mystring & Mystring::operator+(const Mystring &rhs){
    std::cout<<"operator+ called"<<std::endl;
    char *temp = new char[strlen(this->str) + strlen(rhs.str)+ 1];
    strcat(temp,this->str);
    strcat(temp,rhs.str);

    }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include"Mystring.h"


int main(){
    Mystring A {"cat"}; //Overloaded constructor
    Mystring B {"dog"}; //Overloaded constructor
    Mystring C {A};     //Copy constructor
    Mystring D {Mystring{"Hello"}};  //Overloaded and then move constructor
    return 0;
    }
```

Mydoubts:

The  statement `Mystring D {Mystring{"Hello"}};` never invokes move constructor. I don't understand why `Mystring {"Hello"}` doesn't generate any temporary object following which move constructor should be called.

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: It just invokes the overloaded constructor and C does gets the string "Hello". But I dont understand why it fails to invoke the move constructor

Comment: `#define _MYSTRING_H` That identifier is reserved. By defining it, your program will have undefined behaviour. You should use another header guard.

Comment: @VikrantWaje `Mystring::Mystring(const Mystring &source){ delete[] this->str;` -- Undefined behavior, since `str` is not initialized.  Why are you issuing `delete` calls in the copy constructor?  The copy constructor is supposed to create a *brand new* object.  In addition, `operator +` should be returning a new object, not a reference to an existing object.

Comment: "Overloaded" constructor should take const char pointer: `Mystring(const char* str);`

Comment: @VikrantWaje In addition to what PaulMcKenzie said about `operator+`, you should use `strcpy` instead of first `strcat` because newly allocated memory is not zero-initialized and may have garbage. And don't forget to add `return temp;`.

Answer (score 3):

> The statement `Mystring D {Mystring{"Hello"}};` never invokes move constructor

Because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision); which is guaranteed since C++17 for this case.

> When an object is [initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) from a prvalue of the same type (ignoring [cv-qualification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)), it's initialized directly from the initializer. No [temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization) is created, and no copy or move is made. This is sometimes called "guaranteed copy elision", though unlike copy elision, it's mandatory and is not an optimization.

That means given `Mystring D {Mystring{"Hello"}};`, `D` is initialized from `"Hello"` directly. No temporary, no copy / move operation.

Comment: Even if I use     Mystring C = B + A;   the program crashes, why is such behaviour observed then. the operator+ gets invoked successfully but in the copy constructor, the program crashes at strlen() function. 
Any idea about this error?

Comment: @VikrantWaje The program crashes because of other errors, some pointed out in my comments in the main section.

Comment: @VikrantWaje That's another issue; you can get some hints from the comments.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks@PaulMcKenzie
Thanks @songyuanyao